# Keydown event not updating the $scope variable for dropdown in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple page with 2 fields. I enter the goal name and the use tab to navigate to the next field and then hit the down arrow key to select the `Public Group` value and when I click the `save` button, the value of the picklist is setting to `Individual` which is incorrect. I am not exactly sure how to make the `$scope` variable pick the updated value from the dropdown

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx83r873/1/)

```
<div ng-app>
<div class="container" ng-controller="goalCtrl">
<div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">New Record</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="goalName" class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goalName" placeholder="Goal Name" ng-model="goalie__goal__c.Name">
                        </div>  
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fulfilment" class="control-label">Fulfilment</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="fulfilment" ng-model="goalie__goal__c.goalie__Fulfilment__c">
                                <option selected>Individual</option>
                                <option>Public Group</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <center>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()"> Save and add critera</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div></div>
```

**Controller**

```
function goalCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.save = function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.goalie__goal__c));
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update**

I updated the controller where I am setting the value to `Individual` explicitly and then when I hit the save button all the values are updated correctly in the `$scope`. Not sure why its not working it the initial case.

```
function goalCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.goalie__goal__c = {};
    $scope.goalie__goal__c.goalie__Fulfilment__c = 'Individual';
    $scope.save = function() {

        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.goalie__goal__c));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working correctly in Firefox 38.0.5 and Chrome 43.0.2357.124

Comment: I am running it on chrome 42.0.2311.152 and it is failing. But works fine on Firefox..